# Read text file in matlab (data trancation)

Tags: matlab

I am reading a text file in `matlab` . Here is the code

```
allData = textread(file', '%s', 'delimiter', '\n');

numericalArray = cellfun(@(s) sscanf(s,'%f').' ,allData, 'un', 0);
% Get Header
header = allData(cellfun('isempty',numericalArray));
% Get Data
data = vertcat(numericalArray{:});
```

Here is the sample text file

```
head1 head2
760.00 0.3724127064860939
```

**Output:**

```
 data(1,:)

ans =

  760.0000    0.3724
```

the second column value is truncated however, I want to get `0.3724127064860939`

Comment: Are you sure it's not a display issue? Also, `textread` is not recommended by MATLAB.. You should use `textscan` instead.

Comment: yeah. I checked it in workspace @Dev-iL

Comment: with `textscan`, I am able to get the correct values. @Dev-iL

Comment: Yeah but you're unable to get the right values with `textread` either....

Comment: I apologize, with `textscan` values are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to read this sort of data (space-delimited). In all methods precision is preserved.

Assuming you have the input in `demo.txt`:

#### Method 1: simple `textscan`

```
fid = fopen('demo.txt','r'); % open for reading
txt = textscan(fid,'%s','delimiter', '\n'); txt = txt{1}; % read lines and unbox
fclose(fid);

H = strsplit(txt{1},' '); % split the headers line
V = str2double(strsplit(txt{2},' '));
```

#### Method 2: [`dlmread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html)

```
R = dlmread('demo.txt',' ',1,0); % this is an example in the documentation of dlmread
```

#### Method 3: [`readtable`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)

```
T = readtable('demo.txt');
```

Comment: @cswah It works on my system (Win10 + R2017b). When you see the variable in the workspace, make sure you double click the `0.3724`. There's another problem with that method - and that it only works for one row of numbers in the text file.