# How to import tab-delimited data from a text file into a MATLAB array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, file-io, loading, csv

I have a text file that contains 2 columns and `n` number of rows separated by tab as delimiter.

Example `file.txt`:

```
180     -8.3
111    -98.3
111.3    11.22
121      44
```

I want to load the above into MATLAB and have an `n-by-2` array as follows:

```
array[0,0]=180
array[0,1]=-8.3
array[1,1]=111
```

...and so on. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read text file in matlab (data trancation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47122005/read-text-file-in-matlab-data-trancation)

Answer (score 0):

Check [the documentation for `load` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html).

```
myArray = load('myFile.txt', '-ascii'); % return matrix
```

By the way, matlab index starts at 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
array = importdata('file.txt');
```

If it must be an array and not a matrix, check out the matlab function `mat2cell` [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html)